# Reverse Triangle Inequality inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, triangle-inequality

I have a problem proving that for an inner product space over $\mathbb{F}$ this happens:
$$ \|v+u\|\ge\bigl|\|v\|-\|u\|\bigr| $$
My attempt:
$$ \|v+u\|=\sqrt{\langle v,u\rangle+\langle u,v\rangle+\langle v,v\rangle+\langle u,u\rangle} $$
$$ \bigl|\|v\|-\|u\|\bigr|=\left|\sqrt{\langle v,v\rangle}-\sqrt{\langle u,u\rangle}\right| $$
after squaring both sides of the equation we get $$ \langle v,u\rangle+\langle u,v\rangle+\langle v,v\rangle+\langle u,u\rangle?\langle v,v\rangle-2\sqrt{\langle v,v\rangle\langle u,u\rangle}+\langle u,u\rangle $$
we can cancel the same elements and we stay with:
$$ \langle u,v\rangle+\langle v,u\rangle?-2\sqrt{\langle v,v\rangle\langle u,u\rangle} $$
after using $\langle v,u\rangle = \overline{\langle u,v\rangle}$ we stay with:
$$ 2\operatorname{Re}\langle u,v\rangle ? -2\sqrt{\langle v,v\rangle \langle u,u\rangle } $$
After squaring yet again I stay with
$$ \bigl(\operatorname{Re}\langle u,v\rangle\bigr)^2 ?\langle v,v\rangle \langle u,u\rangle $$
How do I go on to prove anything from this? Is my approach completely wrong?

Comment: Note that $v = (u+v) - u$, so by the triangle inequality, $\|v\| \leq \|u+v\| + \|-u\| = \|u+v\| + \|u\|$. You can make a similar argument using $u = (u+v) - v$.

Comment: Thank you very much. 
For proofs such as this, is it 'legal' to use the original triangle inequality?I never proved it for complex numbers

Comment: In that case you should prove the original triangle inequality in the same generality (complex scalars) that you need here. Any book on linear algebra should have a proof. Or see the proof in [this section of the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Example_norms) ("inner product as norm" paragraph). You'll need [Cauchy-Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Proofs) in the same generality, of course.

Answer (score 1):

The approach indicated by @Bungo is doable

let $u = (u+v)-v$

through triangle inequality we get $\|v\| \leq \|u+v\| + \|-u\| = \|u+v\| + \|u\|$ for $\|-u\|=\|u\|$

that is $\|v\|\leq\|v+u\|+\|u\|$

again by letting $v=(v+u)-u$

similarly we get $\|u\|\leq\|v+u\|+\|v\|$

therefore $\|v+u\|$ is greater than or equal to both $\|v\|-\|u\| and -(\|v\|-\|u\|)$

thus $\|v+u\|\geq|\|v\|-\|u\||$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed solution, but as I asked above. Is it legal to use the original triangle inequality to solve this?  
Don't I have to use the inner product and work with linearity until I get it?